# Getting the next key from pandas.read_sql_query().to_dict() and use in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

The data structure that I get back from pulling two columns from the database from:

```
sql = pd.read_sql_query("select Name,FieldType from database.dbo.meta_table where [Table] = 'CLoad'",conn)
```

returns this:

```
 {'Name': {0: 'Item0', 1: 'Item1', 2: 'Item2', 3: 'Item3', 4: 'Item4', 5: 'Item5', 6: 'Item6', 7: 'Item7', 8: 'Item8', 9: 'Item9', 10: 'Item10', 11: 'Item11', 12: 'Item12'}, 'FieldType': {0: 'int', 1: 'int', 2: 'int', 3: 'int', 4: 'date', 5: 'date', 6: 'datetime', 7: 'int', 8: 'bit', 9: 'bit', 10: 'datetime2', 11: 'varchar', 12: 'bit'}}
```

My issue is to create a dictionary from this with output like:

```
{'Item0': 'int', 'Item1': 'int', 'Item2': 'int', 'Item3': 'int', 'Item4': 'date', 'Item5': 'date', 'Item6': 'datetime', 'Item7': 'int', 'Item8': 'bit', 'Item9': 'bit', 'Item10': 'datetime2', 'Item11': 'varchar', 'Item12': 'bit'}
```

I did resolve the problem by hard coding the keys like so:

```
e = {sql['Name'][i]:sql['FieldType'][i] for i in range(len(sql[key]))}
```

But there has to be a way to get the next keys in order programmatically instead. Any help with a better solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `sql` into a `dataframe` and then use **[`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)**:

```
sql =  {'Name': {0: 'Item0', 1: 'Item1', 2: 'Item2', 3: 'Item3', 4: 'Item4', 5: 'Item5', 6: 'Item6', 7: 'Item7', 8: 'Item8', 9: 'Item9', 10: 'Item10', 11: 'Item11', 12: 'Item12'}, 'FieldType': {0: 'int', 1: 'int', 2: 'int', 3: 'int', 4: 'date', 5: 'date', 6: 'datetime', 7: 'int', 8: 'bit', 9: 'bit', 10: 'datetime2', 11: 'varchar', 12: 'bit'}}

output_dict = pd.DataFrame(sql).set_index('Name').to_dict()['FieldType']
```

Output:

```
{'Item0': 'int',
 'Item1': 'int',
 'Item2': 'int',
 'Item3': 'int',
 'Item4': 'date',
 'Item5': 'date',
 'Item6': 'datetime',
 'Item7': 'int',
 'Item8': 'bit',
 'Item9': 'bit',
 'Item10': 'datetime2',
 'Item11': 'varchar',
 'Item12': 'bit'}
```